# Error while uploading Image using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I need help. I have this code that works fine when I am editing text, but when I go to upload any image it gives me error. Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
<div id="page_file">
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="img_upload">
            <input type="file" name="image10" class="image"/>
            <p><span>Note:</span>Image resolution should be exactly  700(width)*500(height) pixels.</p>
        </div><!-- img_upload -->                           
        <input type="submit" name="upload10" class="btn" value="upload"/>
    </form>
<?php

if (isset($_POST['upload10'])) {

    $category_id = 410;
    $exe = end(explode(".", basename($_FILES['image10']['name'])));
    $type = $_FILES['image10']['type'];
    $temp = $_FILES['image10']['tmp_name'];
    $size = $_FILES['image10']['size'];
    $random = rand(1000, 9999);
    $image_id = "img_" . $page_id . $category_id . "_" . $random;
    $name = $image_id . "." . $exe;
    $path = I_UPLOADPATH . $name;
    $img_size = getimagesize($temp);
    $width = $img_size[0];
    $height = $img_size[1];

    $extension = array(
        "image/jpeg",
        "image/jpg",
        "image/png",
        "image/gif"
    );
    if (in_array($type, $extension)) {
        if (($width == 700) && ($height == 500)) {
            if (move_uploaded_file($temp, $path)) {
                $insert = "insert into gallery set srno='', image_id = '" . $image_id . "', title ='" . $name . "', page_id = '" . $page_id . "', category_id = '" . $category_id . "'";
                $execute = mysql_query($insert);

                if (!$execute) {
                    echo "Data Not Procced.....";
                    exit;
                } else {

                    // echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.alert('Upload Successfully.....');</script>";

                    echo ("<script>location.href = 'work.php';</script>");
                }
            } else {
                echo "Error in Upload Image";
            }
        } else {
            echo "You can Upload only 700 * 500 px Image Only";
        }
    } else {
        echo "You can Upload only .JPG, .PNG, .GIF Image.....";
    }
}

?>
</div>
```

This is a part of the code, which normally should work, but displays Image upload error.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: You are using the old, deprecated `mysql` functions - depending upon the version of php you have this may not be available and should not be used. The embedding of variables within the sql means the code is vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: there is no jquery here. You know that right?

Comment: @Anup V is this script runs on linux? if so you should check whether the upload directory has write permissions. Also recheck if your path string is valid